# Is it possible to interact with PC hardware with Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, hardware, adafruit-circuitpython

There are some libraries such as CircuitPython that allow programmers to interact with Arduinos but can one control PC hardware such as the keyboard, usb ports, mouse etc using python?

I have explored various websites but they all focus on controlling Arduinos and Pyboards. I have also tried using the Linux Kernel API (kernel_ffi) but it seems impossible to make a cross-platform script with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to make a Mobile OS and I found that the only way to do that was to interact with the hardware